# Check if a value in one column is in a list in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

[image]

and I need to know if `city` appears in the list in `citylist` (ignoring case).

I've tried to use `apply` like this, but can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['city'].lower() in x['citylist'])
```

Comment: won't `df.apply(lambda x: x['city'].lower() in x['citylist'], axis=1)` work?, your version iterates over each column in turn, you need to pass `axis=1` to iterate row-wise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass param [`axis=1`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to `apply` to iterate row-wise:

```
In [49]:

df[df.apply(lambda x: x['city'].lower() in x['citylist'], axis=1)]
Out[49]:
          city                         citylist
1       RESTON                [reston, herndon]
4  SPRINGFIELD  [springfield, west springfield]
```

Comment: Argh, `axis=1`! Thanks.